# Can MySQL Workbench generate data?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, testing

Is there a way to generate mass rows of dummy data in a table for testing in workbench?

If not, are there any free tools out there that is able to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quickly with SQL if the actual data inserted doesn't matter. Create your table and insert one record manually. If the table has a unique/primary key then remove this for the moment.

Then do a `insert into table select * from table;` This will double the number of records. Do it again to double that (having so 4 records) and so on. Each run will double the (same) records giving you qickly a huge number of them. To make this even faster you can duplicate the query string in the editor. Eg. having 30 insert queries in the editor you can get 2^30 records with a single run of the full editor content.

Once you have enough rows and you want your primary/unique key back run an update over the table, setting the key column to some unique value and then add the primary/unique key back.